# Imitating another document style

Tags: fonts, thesis

### Introduction

I am currently in the process of finishing my thesis. To follow the academic standards that my supervisor has set, I need to imitate the document style shown in the following images as closely as possible.

### Images

[image: chapter 2]

[image: section 2.1]

## Question

What I have so far is shown below. The page format is correct, and I was able to imitate the headers. However the fonts seem to be wrong, and the sizes for the chapters and sections seem off.

Sorry I do not have a access to a scanner or the document in pdf.
Is there an easier way to (or is this style known?), or do I have to hardcode everything to match the images above?

## Code

```
\documentclass[pdftex,
                 10pt, 
              b5paper, 
              twoside, 
                english,
                dvipsnames,
                leqno]{book}

                
\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,
            rmargin=25mm,
            tmargin=27mm,
            bmargin=30mm]{geometry}


    \usepackage{sectsty} %Centers chapters, sections and subsections. 
        \chapterfont{\centering}
        \sectionfont{\centering}
        \subsectionfont{\centering}
        \chapternumberfont{\centering \scshape} 


    \usepackage{xpatch} %Makes the proof environment cursive
    \xpatchcmd{\proof}{\scshape}{\scshape\proofnameformat}{}{}
    \newcommand{\proofnameformat}{\scshape}
    
    
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    
    % Math needs to be loaded before amsthm, so QED can hook into align*
    \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, mathrsfs, mathtools, amsopn} %Mathematical symbols
        
        \usepackage[amsmath, amsthm, thmmarks]{ntheorem} %Defines theorems and definitions
        %
        % Note that we use the same counter [mydef] for definitions, theorems, lemmas, propositions and corolaries
        \theoremstyle{definition} %Non cursive
            \newtheorem{mydef}{\normalfont\scshape Definition\normalfont}[section]
            \newtheorem*{remark}{\normalfont\scshape Remark\normalfont}
        
        \theoremstyle{plain} %cursive 
            \newtheorem{mylemma}[mydef]{\normalfont\scshape Lemma\normalfont}
            \newtheorem{myprop}[mydef]{\normalfont\scshape Proposition\normalfont}
            \newtheorem{mythe}[mydef]{\normalfont\scshape Theorem\normalfont}
            \newtheorem{mycor}[mydef]{\normalfont\scshape Corollary\normalfont}    

\begin{document}

\stepcounter{chapter}

\chapter{Smooth numbers}

\begin{mydef}
    \lipsum[66]
\end{mydef}

\section{Dickman's function}

In this section, we study \emph{Dickman's function} The function $\rho \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by the initial condition $\rho(u) = 1$ for $0 \leq u \leq 1$ and recursively
%
\begin{align}
    \rho(u) = \rho(k) + \int_k^u \rho(v-1) \frac{\mathrm{d}v}v, \quad k \in \mathbb{N}.
\end{align}
%
We obtain the following properties of the Dickman's function. 
\begin{mylemma}
    \lipsum[75]
\end{mylemma}
%
\begin{proof}
    \lipsum[66]
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did your supervisor by any chance ever created a document using LaTeX which matches his opinion of academic standards? If so, you might ask him. Or do you know the person who wrote the above thesis? Recreating a template is/can be tedious (I'm doing this at the moment for my own thesis and my .sty has 900 lines so far).

Comment: This style looks very much like the one from the Polish Academy of Sciences used e.g. by Dissertationes Math.

Comment: Thanks @Christian. My best bet so far is with the *amsbook* package.

Comment: this looks very like the `amsbook` style, except that theorem heads are flush left rather than indented.  if you could identify the book and the publisher, that might provide enough information to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code which should do  what you want, if I've well understood.  I removed the `amsthm` option from `ntheorem` and defined your environments from scratch with the tools of `ntheorem`. For the sections layout, I used  `titlesec`. I also simplified the code, not loading packages which are loaded by other packages (e.g. `` amsopn`is loaded by`amsmath`, which  is loaded by`mathtools`).

```
\documentclass[10pt, b5paper, twoside, english, dvipsnames, leqno]{book}

\usepackage[hmargin=25mm, tmargin=27mm, bmargin=30mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering}{\Large\MakeUppercase{\chaptername~\thechapter}}{2\baselineskip}{\LARGE\bfseries}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\bfseries\centering}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Math needs to be loaded before amsthm, so QED can hook into align*
\usepackage{ amssymb, mathrsfs, mathtools} %Mathematical symbols

\usepackage[amsmath, thmmarks, thref]{ntheorem} %Defines theorems and definitions amsthm,
\theoremstyle{plain} %Non cursive
\theoremheaderfont{\scshape\mdseries}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{.}
    \newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}[section]
    \newtheorem*{remark}{\normalfont\scshape Remark\normalfont}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
    \newtheorem{mylemma}[mydef]{Lemma}
    \newtheorem{myprop}[mydef]{Proposition}
    \newtheorem{mythe}[mydef]{Theorem}
    \newtheorem{mycor}[mydef]{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\begin{document}

\stepcounter{chapter}

\chapter{Smooth numbers}

\begin{mydef}
  \lipsum[66]
\end{mydef}

\section{Dickman's function}

In this section, we study \emph{Dickman's function} The function $ρ\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by the initial condition $ρ(u) = 1$ for $0 \leq u \leq 1$ and recursively
%
\begin{align}
  ρ(u) = ρ(k) + ∫_k^u ρ(v-1) \frac{\mathrm{d}v}v, \quad k ∈ \mathbb{N}.
\end{align}
%
We obtain the following properties of the Dickman's function.
\begin{mylemma}
  \lipsum[75]
\end{mylemma}

\begin{proof}
  Nunc sed pede. Praesent vitae lectus. Praesent neque justo, vehicula eget,
  interdum id, facilisis et, nibh. Phasellus at purus et libero lacinia dictum. Fusce
  aliquet. Nulla eu ante placerat leo semper dictum. Mauris metus. Curabitur
  lobortis. Curabitur sollicitudin hendrerit nunc. Donec ultrices lacus id ipsum.
\end{proof}
```

[image]
    \end{document}